# "Відношення" чи "ставлення"?

Tags: вибір-слова, словосполучення

Як корректніше сформувати вимогу до посади: "бути тактовним у відношенні\ставленні до коллег"? Чи взагалі "по відношенню"?

Comment: А що пишуть словники, в які ви дивилися перед тим, як опублікувати запитання?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Відношення** рідко вживається щодо людей, на що вказує словник [СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/vidnoshennja).

Краще в такому контексті вжати слово **стосунки** в значенні зв'язки, взаємини, які виникають між людьми в процесі спілкування ([СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/stosunok)).

**Ставлення** має близьке значення того чи іншого характеру поводження з ким-, чим-небудь ([СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/stavlennja)), тому теж може бути використане.

Також сам прийменник **до** виражає достатньою мірою зв'язок між словами, тому цілком припустимо взагалі обійтися лише прийменником.

Отже, правильні варіанти:

- **бути тактовним до колег**
- **бути тактовним у стосунках із колегами**
- **бути тактовним у ставленні до колег**